# iOS build issue App Store prefs:root=

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, app-store

I have submitted an iOS build to the App Store and they reject the compilation due to this situation:

> **Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements**
>
> Your app uses the “prefs:root=” non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the
>   associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality
>   using the “prefs:root” or “App-Prefs:root” URL scheme.

This is my IONIC INFO:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
    ios-sim           : 6.1.2
    Node              : v8.11.2
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/ebosques/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Honestly, I don’t have any idea what they refer to.
Can someone help me whit this please I need to make the release in the App Store.

Comment: Code where you write and read files might be also relevant for this question.

Comment: Any luck fixing this, Emir?

Comment: Hi @jckstl, yes I can fix the issue following the indications from the apple support team. Here the solution: 
"Please to check your Xcodes project by simply searching “prefs” - if found the similar URL scheme in codes or plist file, just remove it."

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the use of prefs:root by a cordova plugin.
After a search of the iOS project I have found that it was the diagnostic plugin.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/262

After an update of the plugin it fixed itself.

I also found it might be in the background-geo

https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/454

As a last resort if an update is not available to a broken plugin, deleting the related 
  code from the plugin can solve the problem.